# matlab decimate. change of amplitude depending on the decimation ratio and filter order

Tags: matlab, filter

I have a Pressure signal at 10 kHz that is somewhat noisy. I would therefore like to use the decimate function to reduce the sampling rate and thus reducing the noise.

However, I discovered that depending on the parameters that I put as input to the function, it can happen that the decimate function slightly reduce the amplitude of the signal as well as the amplitude of the noise. I would therefore like to know if somebody could explain me why it is happening in order to ensure that I will be using decimate correctly in the future

As an example, here is different example of the same signal decimated with different parameters. Here I'm just varying the decimation factor r and the order of the Chebyshev Type I lowpass filter n (standard filter used with decimate with n = 8).

if I use n = 8 (standard filter) and r = 4, the output decimated signal (red) has a reduced noise but also a reduced amplitude compared to the original signal (blue):

[image: graph with n=8 and r = 4]

```
figure;n = 8;r=4;plot(TimeFyr,Pup,decimate(TimeFyr,r,n),decimate(Pup,r,n),'r')
```

Actually, every even order for the filter (so n = 2*k, k€int) give me the same results, whereas for the odd order (n = 2*k+1) the amplitude is conserved:

graph with n = 9 and r = 4:

[image: graph with n = 9 and r = 4]

```
figure;n = 9;r=4;plot(TimeFyr,Pup,decimate(TimeFyr,r,n),decimate(Pup,r,n),'r')
```

also, the same holds true if I increase the decimation factor up to 90

n = 9 and r = 90:

[image: n = 9 and r = 90]

```
figure;n = 9;r=90;plot(TimeFyr,Pup,decimate(TimeFyr,r,n),decimate(Pup,r,n),'r')
```

if now I increase the decimation factor above 90, the amplitude is decreased for any decimation factor and any filter order, except for the 3rd order:

n = 9 and r = 91 (amplitude decreased):

[image: n = 9 and r = 91]

```
figure;n = 9;r=91;plot(TimeFyr,Pup,decimate(TimeFyr,r,n),decimate(Pup,r,n),'r')
```

n = 6 and r = 100 (amplitude decreased):

[image: n = 6 and r = 100]

```
figure;n = 6;r=100;plot(TimeFyr,Pup,decimate(TimeFyr,r,n),decimate(Pup,r,n),'r')
```

n = 3 and r = 100 (amplitude conserved!):

[image: n = 3 and r = 100]

```
figure;n = 3;r=100;plot(TimeFyr,Pup,decimate(TimeFyr,r,n),decimate(Pup,r,n),'r')
```

Finally, for very big decimation factor (>500), the amplitude is conserved no matter which order I use for the filter. I tried to vary the length of the source vector and this holds true.

I'm sure that I'm missing some theoretical background on how filters work and how those parameters can influence the output, but I find a bit weird that the output of the function can be "wrong" (ie with here lower amplitude of the signal, along with the noise) just depending on the parameters I use.

Especially weird is the fact that Matlab tells you in the "help decimate" that for better results at large decimation factor (ie r>13) it is recommended to break r up into its factors and calling decimate several time. So for a decimation factor of 1000, matlab suggest to decimate the signal by 2 three times and by 5 three time (2*2*2*5*5*5 = 1000). if I do that the distance between the source signal and the decimated vector increase even more, whereas with directly a ratio of 1000, the output signal has the same amplitude!

Comparison with recursive call or directly with r = 1000, n = 6:

[image: Comparison with recursive call or directly with r = 1000, n = 6]

```
figure;n = 6;plot(TimeFyr,Pup,decimate(decimate(decimate(decimate(TimeFyr,4,n),10,n),5,n),5,n),decimate(decimate(decimate(decimate(Pup,4,n),10,n),5,n),5,n),'r')

figure;n = 6;r=1000;plot(TimeFyr,Pup,decimate(TimeFyr,r,n),decimate(Pup,r,n),'r')
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Hello and Welcome to SO. When talking about decimation, it is important to know what the sampling rate of your recorded signal is and what the magnitude spectrum of your original data looks like. Once you designed your filter have a look on the spectrum, especially in the frequency band of interest. Some other notes. It is very difficult to reproduce your results as we dont have a minimum example with the desired input output behavior (see [ask]). You should also always label your axis when showing figures. This way everybody knows what he/she is looking at.

Comment: Additional thoughts: you dont need to decimate your x axis, just take every other sample. It seems you are choosing your decimation factor arbitrary without taking the sampling rate into account. Despite all these points it is unclear why you need to decimate your data if all what you want to do is filter your signal in a certain frequency band?

Comment: If the signal of interest has any energy in the frequencies that you are eliminating, then its energy in the time domain will be commensurately reduced. Since any practical signal will have some amount of energy at all frequencies, the idea of filtering is to eliminate much more noise power than signal power, so that you see an increase in the SNR.

Comment: Thank you for your preliminary elements! indeed I have a lack of background on signal processing and most likely my question is purely related to this.

Comment: My goal is to obtain a curve with a much lower noise, but keeping the main "evolution profile". it is to be used for post-processing, where I don't need that many data point (original signal at 10 kHz), and to be placed in a report. Basically, my goal is to obtain the right red curve of the last picture: the down-sampled signal follows the evolution of the original signal (in blue) while being much less noisy. I can update the post if needed.

Comment: I'm also open to suggestion if other Matlab functions are more suited for my application. I thought the decimate function was perfect as very simple to use at a primary look. but in any case, I'm still perplex as to why the order of the filter (basically how fast the amplitude sink at the end of the bandwidth) can make such a big difference between a signal that keep the same amplitude and one that is diminished. let me know if I need to add some more information on the original signal

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the choice of filter. Chebyshev 1, if that is what you are using, does attenuate at low frequencies https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_filter.
Chebyshev 2 or Butterworth would be a better choice since they do not have much of a ripple in a passband. Pleased, see the Wikipedia about the filters, and it will be clear. Yes, the choice of filter is extremely important when doing decimation.